# Bootstrap Datetimepicker not functioning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am experimenting with the excellent Bootstrap DateTimePicker plugin but appear to have hit the buffers right at the start.  The page control appears correctly but the calendar button is entirely unresponsive - no picker actually pops up.  I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ff6jguv/5/) to illustrate the problem.  Examining the console output for the fiddle does not reveal anything obviously wrong.

I noticed that the sample code uses jQuery 1.8.3 so I tried dropping back to that but to no avail. What am I getting wrong here?

The test markup I am using is quite straightforward - and copied directly from the Datetimepicker example docs

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dtp_singleshot" class="col-md-2 control-label">Choose</label>
  <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-link-
   field="dtp_singleshot">
  <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
  </div>
<input type="hidden" id="dtp_singleshot" value="" /><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to remove `readonly` attribute from your `input`. You don't need second hidden input. Then you have to assign `id` of `dtp_singleshot` to your `input-group` or `input`.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dtp_singleshot" class="col-md-2 control-label" id="dtp_singleshot">Choose</label>
  <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-link-
   field="dtp_singleshot">
  <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0ff6jguv/4/)

Comment: Perfect!  I take it that this means the sample code in the docs is somehow wrong?  I notice a mention somewhere that the sample code is for the v4 beta.

Comment: I couldn't find this example in the docs. Can you give a link?

Comment: I wonder if I have not accidentally been using a forked version - the one I am using comes from [here](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php). In the ZIP available from there you will find the markup I have used in _sample in bootstrap v3/index.html_

Comment: It is different plugin. Here you have docs for plugin you use. http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Yes, I realized that once I examined things more closely after reading your answer.  The two plugins are very similar to one another. I had grabbed the original code a while ago - and started using the online docs for the wrong one without realizing it.